# What would be best way to show N number of column as per no of days in month

Tags: sql-server-2005

i want to show this kind of output

```
UserID  UserName 1  2  3 30
```

OR

```
UserID  UserName 1  2  3 31
```

user data saved in db `select distinct UserID,Name from Userss Where IsActive=1 and order by UserID`

and i want to just calculate no of days in month based on year and month name supplied by user.

one way i can do it. first i will create a temporary table and in loop add many columns to that table and later dump user data to specific column. i am not sure am i thinking in right direction. anyone can come up with suggestion or code sample to achieve it. thanks

### EDIT

just got a function which will return no of days as per date. here it is

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ufn_GetDaysInMonth] ( @pDate    DATETIME )
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN

    RETURN CASE WHEN MONTH(@pDate) IN (1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12) THEN 31
                WHEN MONTH(@pDate) IN (4, 6, 9, 11) THEN 30
                ELSE CASE WHEN (YEAR(@pDate) % 4    = 0 AND
                                YEAR(@pDate) % 100 != 0) OR
                               (YEAR(@pDate) % 400  = 0)
                          THEN 29
                          ELSE 28
                     END
           END

END
GO

select [dbo].[ufn_GetDaysInMonth](CAST('06/01/2015' as datetime))
```

so now my concern is to generate column dynamically with user id and name and no of months. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this for the date:

```
DECLARE @Month VARCHAR(15)
DECLARE @Year SMALLINT
DECLARE @date DATETIME 
SET @Month = 'February'
SET @Year = 2015
SET @date = '01 ' + @Month + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),@Year)

/*Here is the action part:*/    
SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, @date, DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @date))
```

For the other requirement research computed columns:

[MSDN:  How to: Specify Computed Columns (Visual Database Tools)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms188300(v=sql.90).aspx)

Here is the detail from that page:

**To specify a computed column**

1. In Object Explorer, right-click the table with columns for which you
   want to specify a computed column and click Design (Modify in SP1 or
   earlier). The table opens in Table Designer.
2. Select the column for which you want to specify a computed column
   formula.
3. In the Column Properties tab, expand the Computed Column Specification property. In the (Formula) child property, type the expression for this column in the grid cell to the right.  For example, ColumnA + ColumnB.
4. Indicate whether the data is persisted by choosing Yes or No from the    drop-down for the Is Persisted child property.

Comment: my main concern is how to generate column dynamically with user id and name and no of months. thanks

Answer (score -1):

ALTER TABLE table_name
  ADD COLUMN column_name column-definition;Psuedo Code if I understood your question right

```
Check Year (for Leap years)
If (leapYear == true)
{
    if (month = 1,3,5,7,8,10,12) 
        days = 31
    else if (month = 4,6,9,11) 
        days = 30
    else 
        days =29  
}
else
{
    if (month = 1,3,5,7,8,10,12) 
        days = 31
    else if (month = 4,6,9,11) 
        days = 30
    else 
        days =28 
}
for (i=1;i<=days;i++)
     ALTER TABLE table_name
     ADD COLUMN column_name column-definition; // u get columns added as per number of days
```

Comment: i am talking about sql server not c#.